# .Net MVC Model Creation based on SQL Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

In .NET MVC I want to create a model/class that the constructor builds the object based on a SQL query, based on a user id. So when a user login in that object is instantiated based on that user.

something roughly like:
query = SELECT * from table1 where userid = userid

public class MyClass(int UserID){
         some sort of for loop for the query result to set object properties
}

Finally... where is the best place to create that object in a .NET MVC application that any controller can access it? Or perhaps a way to set user variables based on SQL queries that all controllers have access to?

I have a feeling there is an MVC way to do this... just not sure what that is.I am using .Net Framework 4.5.1 and MVC version 5.2.3.0, Owin 3.0.1, and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Not the MVC way, but I did figure out how to run a query:
    dn_dbEntitiesFWConn _db;
              Model var = _db.tablename.SqlQuery("SQL QUERY HERE").FirstOrDefault();